# How to pass stdin to python script

Tags: linux, python, alias

I'd like to pass input from a shell command over to a python script in an alias that uses a shell command.

test.py:

```py
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

the alias

```bash
alias foo='echo $(python test.py $1)'
```

since `$ python cd_alias_test.py hello` would print all the args: `['test.py', 'hello']`
I'd expect this alias to do the same.  However its stdout is

```
['test.py'] hello
```

Which means that the input string is being passed to stdin and not the script's arguments.

How I achieve the intended effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alias test='echo $(python test.py $1)'
```

`$1` is not defined in an alias, *aliases aren't shell functions*; they're just text replacement; so your `test hello` gets expanded to `echo $(python test.py ) hello`, which gets expanded to `echo ['test.py'] hello`.

If you want a shell function, write one! (and don't call your function or alias `test`, that name is already reserved for the logical evaluation thing in your shell).

```bash
function foo() { echo $(python test.py $1) }
foo hello
```

But one really has to wonder: Why not simply make `test.py` executable (e.g. `chmod 755 test.py`) and include the `#!/usr/bin/env python3` first line in it? Then you can just run it directly:

```bash
./test.py hello darkness my old friend
```

Comment: Functionally speaking `echo $(thing)` could/should just be `thing` -- otherwise there's a risk of `echo` interpreting the output of `thing` as switches it should care about, e.g. `echo $(printf "%s" "-n hello") ; echo world`

Comment: @bxm that might be the intention here!

Comment: I understand how functions are more appropriate for this task, but I'm still a little confused as to how arguments like $1 are not defined in an alias.  For instance if I have `alias foo='python cd_alias_test.py $1'`, then the output for `$ foo hello` will be ['cd_alias_test.py', 'hello']

Comment: they're simply... not defined. There's nothing setting up a variable called `$1`, because an alias gets expanded to its value as if you just typed that in. So, your `foo hello` looks like you typed in `python cd_alias_test.py $1 hello` and that gets expanded to `python cd_alias_test.py  hello` before execution. There's really no magic here. Just your assumption about what an alias does being a bit wrong, it seems! An alias doesn't take "arguments". An alias simply doesn't "exist" as programming construct: it gets replaced by its value before *anything* gets defined, expanded…

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusingly worded, but I seems you just want to execute an alias passing a parameter to your script.

I think this is what you want.

```
alias runtest='python test.py'
```

As otherwise mentioned, shell functions can be preferable to aliases -- allowing for less trivial arg handling.

So in this example:

```
function runtest() { python test.py "$1" ; }
```